# Maximum likelihood estimator based on 1 datum for non-canonical discrete distribution

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, discrete-data

One observation is taken from a discrete distribution with a parameter $\theta$.  There are 3 possible values of $\theta$: 1, 2, and 3.  The PMF is given below.

[image]

What is the MLE of $\theta$?

I suspect that $X = 3$ has something to do with the answer, because it has non-zero probabilities for all 3 values of $\theta$.

I also know that the MLE cannot be terribly complicated, because there is only one observation to work with.

Comment: It depends on the sample value x you have drawn. MLE maximizes the likelihood of observing the data with regard to the parameter. There is no MLE without data.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: This looks like the right answer!  Thank you!  Would you be so kind to write it as an answer, so that I can vote it as a solution?

Comment: In this question, the MLE is considered to be a *function* defined on the sample space, with image in the parameter space.  The question provides enough information to define an MLE.

Comment: can I convert this to a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\hat \theta $ be the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$.

$$\hat \theta = \begin{cases}
        1, & \text{for } X = 0 \text{ or } 1\\
        2, & \text{for } X = 3\\
        3, & \text{for } X=4\\
        2 \text{ with prob 0.5 and 3 with prob 0.5}&\text{for } X=2
        \end{cases}
 $$

Comment: This may just be convention, but I'm not used to seeing a stochastic maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: @a_statistician If $X=2$, then is it correct to say that $\hat{\theta} = 2.5$?  I say this because the average value of the 2 values of $\theta$ for that particular value of $X$ is 2.5.

Comment: $\hat \theta = 2.5$ is not the answer for this problem. If $X=2$, find a fair coin, specify head to 2, throw coin, if head $\hat \theta = 2$, otherwise $\hat \theta = 3$